# lvalue required as unary '&' operand while finding offset of a structure variable inside an another structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to access elements i, f and ch of the following structure.

```
struct a{
    struct b{
        int i;
        float f;
        char ch;
    }x;

    struct c{
        int j;
        float g;
        char ch;
    }y;
};
```

This has to be done by passing the address of structure c to a function and calculating its offset to access structure b

```
struct a z;
fun(&z.y);
```

The function is as follows:

```
fun(struct c *p){

    int offset;
    struct b *address;
    offset = (char *) &((struct c*)(&((struct a*)0)->y)->j) - (char *)((struct a*)0);
    address = (struct b*)((char *)&(p->j)-offset);
    address->i = 400;
    address->f = 3.14;
    address->ch = 'c';

}
```

Despite trying a lot, it always gives an error of `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

I know the meaning of the error, but isn't able to get it done here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `offsetof` rather than arithmetic on phony "members of structs at the null pointer" anyway.  For this, you just need more than one `offsetof` computed.  (Yes, sometimes `offsetof` is implemented like that, but only if and because the compiler team knows it will work for that compiler.)

Comment: The line should be `offset = offsetof(struct a, y.j);`

Comment: @xing technically UB but would probably work

Answer (score 2):

`&` can only be used on variables (including array elements or struct members) - more formally called *lvalues*. Essentially, you can use it on anything that could be on the left side of an `=` (this is how lvalues got their name). You can't do, for example, `&(1 + 1)`. You also can't do `&(&some_variable)` for the same reason: `&some_variable` is not an lvalue.

It's easy to see these are not lvalues, as you couldn't do `1 + 1 = something;` or `&some_variable = something;`.

You have `&((struct c*)(&((struct a*)0)->y)->j)`. Or simplified, `&(&(something))`. This is not valid. I don't know what the function is trying to do, but perhaps you've used two `&`s instead of one by a simple mistake.